# libgdx java.lang.NoSuchFieldError: glu

Tags: java, eclipse, libgdx

i am newbie using the libgdx library. When running my desktop game in eclipse i am getting error (see below)

```
Exception in thread "LWJGL Application" com.badlogic.gdx.utils.GdxRuntimeException: java.lang.NoSuchFieldError: glu
    at com.badlogic.gdx.backends.lwjgl.LwjglApplication$1.run(LwjglApplication.java:113)
Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchFieldError: glu
    at com.badlogic.gdx.backends.lwjgl.LwjglGraphics.initiateGLInstances(LwjglGraphics.java:249)
    at com.badlogic.gdx.backends.lwjgl.LwjglGraphics.setupDisplay(LwjglGraphics.java:184)
    at com.badlogic.gdx.backends.lwjgl.LwjglApplication.mainLoop(LwjglApplication.java:122)
    at com.badlogic.gdx.backends.lwjgl.LwjglApplication$1.run(LwjglApplication.java:110)
```

I think i am using the wrong jars but i don't know

Thanks.

Comment: Yes, this usually indicates that you have the wrong version of the jar on your classpath.

Comment: Thx suresh, how do find out what is the right verion?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

to fix the jars in your game run gdx-setup-ui.jar and update your game. Thats it. 
And always use gdx-setup-ui.jar before building your game. This will prevent errors in future.